# How to use uniform distribution to see central limit theorem in action?

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability-density, probability-distribution, uniform-distribution

I would like to use MATLAB to visualize the Central Limit Theorem in action. I would like to use `rand()` to produce 10 samples of uniform distribution `U[0,1]` and compute their average, then save it to a matrix 'Mat'.

I would then use a histogram to visualize the convergence in distribution. How would you do this and normalize that histogram so it is a valid probability density (instead of just counting the frequency of occurrence)?

To generate the samples I am doing something like:

```
Mat = rand(N,sizeOfVector) > rand(1);
```

But I guess I am going  to the wrong side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate `N` samples of length `sizeOfVector` you start out with `rand` as you suggested, and then continue as follows (calling the array `average` instead of `Mat` for readability):

```
samples = rand(N,sizeOfVector);

average = mean(samples,1);

binWidth = 3.49*std(average)*N^(-1/3)); %# Scott's rule for good bin width for normal data
nBins = ceil((max(average)-min(average))/binWidth);

[counts,x] = hist(average,nBins);

normalizedCounts = counts/sum(counts);

bar(x,normalizedCounts,1)
```

Comment: Excuse, what would be Scott's rule for number of bins, that gen `0´s` ans `1's`

Comment: @darkcminor: sorry, thought that the formula was giving number of bins, instead it's giving bin width (using the default 10 bins of `hist` is not going to be very pretty, btw). Fixed the answer.